# Skip all leading empty lines in read.csv

Tags: r, import, read.csv

I am wishing to import csv files into R, with the first non empty line supplying the name of data frame columns. I know that you can supply the `skip = 0` argument to specify which line to read first. However, the row number of the first non empty line can change between files.

How do I work out how many lines are empty, and dynamically skip them for each file?

As pointed out in the comments, I need to clarify what "blank" means. My csv files look like:

```
,,,
w,x,y,z
a,b,5,c
a,b,5,c
a,b,5,c
a,b,4,c
a,b,4,c
a,b,4,c
```

which means there are rows of commas at the start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`read.csv` automatically skips blank lines (unless you set `blank.lines.skip=FALSE`).  See `?read.csv`

After writing the above, the poster explained that blank lines are not actually blank but have commas in them but nothing between the commas.  In that case use `fread` from the data.table package which will handle that. The `skip=` argument can be set to any character string found in the header:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("myfile.csv", skip = "w") # assuming w is in the header
DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
```

The last line can be omitted if a data.table is ok as the returned value.

Comment: Good catch. So long as the 'empty' lines are totally empty of any characters this should just work. OP should probably clarify the nature of their data.

Comment: I did try to use `blank.lines.skip = TRUE`, and I was wondering why it did not work. It turns out that the blank lines contain commas.

Comment: Is there any minus of skipping empty lines in performance? - - I have every second line empty in my attempt, actually every odd line is blank. - - I like to keep the data as original as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your file size, this may be not the best solution but will do the job.

Strategy here is, instead of reading file with delimiter, will read as lines,
and count the characters and store into temp.
Then, while loop will search for first non-zero character length in the list,
then will read the file, and store as data_filename.

```
flist = list.files()
for (onefile in flist) {
  temp = nchar(readLines(onefile))
  i = 1
  while (temp[i] == 0) {
    i = i + 1
  }
  temp = read.table(onefile, sep = ",", skip = (i-1))
  assign(paste0(data, onefile), temp)
}
```

If file contains headers, you can start i from 2.

Answer (score 2):

If the first couple of empty lines are truly empty, then `read.csv` should automatically skip to the first line. If they have commas but no values, then you can use:

```
df = read.csv(file = 'd.csv')
df = read.csv(file = 'd.csv',skip = as.numeric(rownames(df[which(df[,1]!=''),])[1]))
```

It's not efficient if you have large files (since you have to import twice), but it works.

If you want to import a tab-delimited file with the same problem (variable blank lines) then use:

```
df = read.table(file = 'd.txt',sep='\t')
df = read.table(file = 'd.txt',skip = as.numeric(rownames(df[which(df[,1]!=''),])[1]))
```

Comment: spot on with the commas, but this would also work with tab separated as well right?

Comment: Not with the `read.csv` function. You'll get an error since the function is looking for commas.