# Skip lines containing only commas in csv files

Tags: r, csv

How to read csv files so that lines containing only commas are skipped?

[Skip all leading empty lines in read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456814/skip-all-leading-empty-lines-in-read-csv)
covers couple ideas for the case that these lines are in the beginning of the file, but what about a more generic solution?

Comment: @csgillespie The header says "only commas" so a blank line.

Comment: @csgillespie: No, I want to delete all lines containing just commas - e.g. no values.

Comment: My guess is that this will be easiest to read the whole file in and then drop those rows.

Comment: @lmo: Yes, but when reading factor variables, levels are already messed up. I know, I can read it as string and drop lines, convert to factor - but that takes more time.

Comment: It is a good ideas to always use the as.is=TRUE when using `read.csv` or friends. This reads non numeric columns as strings. You can perform conversion to factors further down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the performance but you can do this with the help of `readLines(), grepl()` and `writeLines()` function:

Assuming input file is A.csv and the output CSV file (though not necessary)which will not contain commas be B.csv.

```
test <- readLines('A.csv')

test2 <- test[!grepl(",",test)]
```

Either you can use `test2` variable or save that to B.csv:

```
writeLines(test2,'B.csv')
```

Comment: It is somewhat heavy, but it seems to do the job. There is probably no ideal answer to the question, so I have accepted the answer. :)